# Android Layout - fill the rest of the space except

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relative layout. For simplicity, there is an `ImageView`, `EditText`, and `Button`:

- The `ImageView` is a banner with a fixed height
- Below that is and the `EditText` where `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
- Below that is a `Button` with a fixed width and height

The problem is I want the `editText` to fill the leftover height of the screen. put and image on the top, a button on the bottom, and in the middle and edit text that takes up the rest of the space.

What property would i have to work with to get something similar to this?

Comment: minor point: "fill_parent" is deprecated. Use "match_parent" instead. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT

Answer (score 68, accepted):

For this purpose, there is `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` property. Use `LinearLayout` for holding these 3 elements. For `Button` and `ImageView`, set `layout_height` as `wrap_content`. For `EditText` set `layout_height="0dp"` and **`layout_weight="1"`**.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html)?

You could use

```
android:layout_below

android:layout_alignParentTop

android:layout_alignParentBottom

android:layout_marginTop

android:layout_marginBottom
```

Try that and post some sample code if you get stuck.